# Анимация сразу двух div'ов

Tags: jquery, html

Каким образом в jQuery задействовать анимацию сразу двух элементов. Надо чтобы один выезжал а другой уезжал...

Я пробовал так:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnAr").click(function(){
       $("#Preview1").slideToggle("slow");
       $("#article1").slideToggle("slow");
    });  
 });
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="preview" id="preview1">
            ....
    <div>
    <a href="#" class="btnAr" id="butAr1">Подробнее...</a>
        <div class="article" id="article1">
                ... 
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.article
{
 padding: 10px 10px;
 position: static;
 display: none;
}

div.preview
{
 padding: 10px 10px;
 position: static;
 display: block;
 font: 10 Verdana;
}
```

но срабатывает только один...

Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**//UPD**

```
   <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".btnAr").click(
    function()
    {
       $("#preview1").slideToggle("slow");
       $("#article1").slideToggle("slow");
    }
    );

});
  </script>

<div class="article" id="article1">
   Второй ДИВ
   <a href="#" class="btnAr" id="butAr1">Развернуть</a>    
</div>
<div class="preview" id="preview1">
    Первый див
   <a href="#" class="btnAr" id="butAr1">Свернуть</a>
<div>
```

Все работает.
У тебя наверное и текст пропадает при нажатии на ссылку, если да, то ссылку вставь в DIV как у меня и все гуд.

Comment: не работает.. первый не уезжает...(

Comment: Ну я бы тоже не уезжал

Comment: все работает) Спасибо) поменял местами div как вы написали... но почему не работало как я делал?..

Comment: Ну из описания slideToggle

**Переключает видимость всех совпавших элементов набора, используя эффект изменения высоты элементов. 
Для данного типа анимации используется лишь изменение высоты, что позволяет раскрывать элементы в “скользящий” способ. **

Ну вот скорее всего просто накладывались друг на друга.

Answer (score 1):

Вы в курсе, что id регистрозависимый?)

```
//"Preview1" != "preview1"
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btnAr").click(function() {
       $("#preview1").slideToggle("slow");
       $("#article1").slideToggle("slow");
      });   
  });
```

Ну [не может](http://sh4dow.jino.ru/test26.php) оно не работать)

Comment: Я сначала не заметил, я уже исправил.

Comment: уезжает только  $("#preview1"), а $("#article1") не выезжает...

Comment: регистр эт да) в исходнике все правильно, эт я тут накалякал...

Comment: Обновил, добавил ссыль на рабочий вариант. Проверьте айдишники все-таки) Мне кажется, у вас какая-нибудь опечатка или что-то подобное.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего это какие-то внутренние проблемы с таймерами внутри jquery, это можно проверить - попробуйте:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $(".btnAr").click(
                function() {
                    $("#Preview1").slideToggle("slow",
                        function () {
                            $("#article1").slideToggle("slow")
                        }
                    );
                }
        );   
    }
);
```

Если это будет работать (я понимаю, что не одновременно) - выполнять функцию: один контейнер убрать, а другой показать. То значит проблема в jquery :-(

**UPDATE**

Хотя я проверил: http://jsfiddle.net/chernomyrdin/ya35t/ - все нормально